# How to normalize '1:2:3' to '01:02:03' by using re module of Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to normalize strings like

```
'1:2:3','10:20:30'
```

to

```
'01:02:03','10:20:30'
```

by using re module of Python, 
so I am trying to select the string like '1:2:3' then match the single number '1','2','3'..., here is my pattern:

```
^\d(?=\D)|(?<=\D)\d(?=\D)|(?<=\D)\d$
```

it works but I think the pattern is not simple enough, anybody could help me simplify it? or use map()/split() if it's more sophisticated.

Comment: So each single digit is to be turned into `0<singledigit>` ????

Comment: Your pattern matches a TON of different strings. You probably want to narrow down what `strings like '1:2:3' ` means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['1:2:3','10:20:30']
>>> [re.sub(r'\b(\d)\b', r'0\1', i) for i in l]
['01:02:03', '10:20:30']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eL3zL4/1)

Comment: So you mean digit is also a word character, I thought \b only matches characters which is English word such as 'banana'..but anyway, thank u very mach!

Comment: yep, `a-z,A-Z,0-9,_` are word chars.

Comment: It's so cool, `re.sub(r'\b(\d)\b', r'0\1', '11|2|3')` will simple got my expect `'11|02|03'`. There `re` may have many useful , how do i learn it and keep it in my mind?

Comment: learn regex,it would be awesome. Well, I suggest this https://www.regular-expressions.info/ link for all my friends.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(r"(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)",r"0\1",test_str)
```

You can simplify it to this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nD5jY4/4#python

If the string is like

```
x="""'1:2:3','10:20:30'"""
```

Then do

```
print ",".join([re.sub(r"(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)",r"0\1",i) for i in x.split(",")])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `re`, but pretty much nobody will know how it works afterwards. I'd recommend this instead:

```
':'.join("%02d" % int(x) for x in original_string.split(':'))
```

It's more clear how it works.